# How to create helm variable with a comma

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm wanting to create a helm variable with just a comma. I'm not sure how I'd do it? I ran into syntax issues with the below.

```
{{- $asterisk := "*" }}
{{- $comma := ",\" }}
```

The result would be appended using printf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commas aren't special in the Go text/template language, and you don't need to escape them in strings.

```
{{- $comma := "," -}}
```

You can put literal text into `printf` and this may be easier for your uses

```
{{ printf "%s, %s" $var1 $var2 }}
```